# In an HTML file I want to look for a series of text inputs and have it replaced with other inputs

Tags: html

So this is for an idea for fun joke-page, for a few friends, but I can't seem to get any code to work. I basically want to take a well known webpage and create a script that will search through out and replace certain words or phrases with others.. So for example, say, every time the word dog is on the webpage-- I want it replaced with hat... or every time "..." is on the page, it would be replaced with "!!!"--- as just an example.

How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a bit of javascript in the body of your page to search and replace specific words:

```
<script>
input = 'dog';
output='hat';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(input,output);
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbaXj/)

Comment: Great, that works-- however for replacing "..." like in the phrase "Hello how are you..." seems difficult, and the character codes for periods "&#46;" doesn't seem to trigger anything...